# AltBeacon distance calculation procedure

Tags: android, distance, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm using AltBeacon as an iBeacon distance calculator. I have recently started to measure my device to be able to add the results to the database https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/resources/model-distance-calculations.json

I followed the steps provided on https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations2.html

When I used the original data which is already in the spreadsheet (from the link provided on the page linked above), I noticed that the data there is far off. When using the data and running it through http://www.xuru.org/rt/powr.asp
I got totally different coefficients A and B. In case of the data in the spreadsheet it is: **y = 4.295400587 * x ^ 6.170094565** So this means that **A = 4.295400587** and **B = 6.170094565** In the spreadsheet however it is **A = 1.203420305** and **B = 6.170094565**

Furthermore when I checked the provided data with the library https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/resources/model-distance-calculations.json
I noticed that there is only one model with coefficient B equal to provided (and it is not **Nexus 5** as stated, but **Moto X Pro**). The other coefficient (I'm talking about A here as I didn't even go as far as calculating C) is even different than in example spreadsheet.

Does anyone know how things should be calculated and if I can even rely on provided steps if they are so far off in so many places?

I want to calculate the distance from the beacon and adjust the data based on the smartphones "receiving capabilities".

Thanks

Comment: There are different tools for running power regressions which produce different results. I believe the R stats programming language was used for some existing regressions.  Figuring out how to reproduce exact coefficients may be difficult.  What is important is that any new calculations generate coefficients that are able to reasonably predict the data set.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We will use the data as it comes and at some later point will probably have to run some comparison tests.